# Finding out what makes your file size big?

Tags: memory-management

Is there a way to see exactly which objects/textures/etc in my scene take up the most memory? My scenes often get rather big, bigger than I feel they should be, and rendering them obviously then tends to take quite some time.
So is there a way to see what uses the most data/memory?

Thanks.

(I'm not at liberty to share these files.)

Comment: Hi, your files are not needed, imho. Have you sen this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72098/is-there-an-easy-way-to-see-what-is-consuming-the-most-memory ?

Comment: Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67630/blender-2-78-file-size-grows-and-does-never-shrink

Comment: A real answer to this question would be really nice.  So far the best I can find is to "delete randomly and check file size". https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45665/33487