# Is there a way to change default values of properties of operator?

Tags: customization, operator

I tried this to change, but no success
[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you specifically looking to do this with Python?

Comment: Possibly related re example operator used https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45664/how-do-i-reduce-my-file-size

Comment: @RayMairlot No, I just wanna save needed default values of tneeded operators like settings in user preferences. Python solution would be great - I'll write what I want to .py file and drop the file to the startup folder. Python is only possible option here

Comment: Updated the tags to reflect this. Generally tags are for the question, not for potential solutions.

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks a lot! Useful in my case. But still, it would be great to have a way to change any default value without recoding Blender in C

Comment: Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101355/15543